# Why doesn't my guard & spork setup reload code in lib?

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard, spork

I'm using spork with guard. It correctly reloads spec and project code when it changes. But it doesn't reload code in lib. If I change code in lib, I have to restart guard. Even more odd, guard recognizes the code file being changed and reruns the correct spec. But, that code is not reloaded.

(to be honest i'm not even sure what layer of the system is responsible for reloading code into spork... without reloading spork)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your code is loaded before Spork's prefork. Did you try using [Spork in diagnostic mode](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork#diagnostic-mode) to see when the code is getting loaded?

```
spork --diagnose | less
```